# uncheck all dynamically created checkboxes in android in a layout

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a method like this:

```
public void initialiseCheckBox(){

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Banners");
    list.add("Poster");
    list.add("Stickers");

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        checkBox = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        checkBox.setId(i);
        checkBox.setText(list.get(i));

        FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.rightMargin = 32;
        params.topMargin = 5;

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(checkBox));
        linearMain.addView(checkBox, params);
    }

}
```

I can get all the selected `CheckBox` via the getOnClickDoSomething(checkBox) now how can I uncheck all the checked `CheckBox` in a different method am using a fragment. Thank you

Comment: checkBox.setChecked(false);

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

First populate an ArrayList of checkboxes:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> arrayOfCheckBox = new ArrayList<>();
      for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        checkBox = new CheckBox(getActivity());
        checkBox.setId(i);
        checkBox.setText(list.get(i));

        FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.rightMargin = 32;
        params.topMargin = 5;

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(checkBox));
        arrayOfCheckBox.add(checkBox);
        linearMain.addView(checkBox, params);
    }
```

Then uncheck the checkboxes of the arraylist:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myCheckBoxes.size(); i++) {
        myCheckBoxes.get(i).setChecked(false);
    }
```

Tell me if solve your problem please.(SOLVED)

Comment: it worked but i changed setSelected(false); TO  setChecked(false);,  Thank u so much

Comment: Nice ill edit, can you put my answer as accepted? Thank you